# How to pass the disabled condition, in the ionic button component

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have the following component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss'],
  template: `
              <ion-button color="{{color}}" (click)="action.emit(null)" [disabled]="condition">
                {{title}}
              </ion-button>
            `
})

export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public title: string;
  @Input() public color = 'primary';
  @Input() public condition: any;

  @Output() public action = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

But when I pass the boolean out of it it does not render, because I have a boolean that starts false and becomes true according to the input.

edit: the problem is when validDocument becomes true, the button does not render again and remains disabled.

HTML declaration:

```
<app-button title="Buscar" (action)="go()" condition="!validDocument"></app-button>
```

Comment: try with [disabled]="{{condition}}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, // force a component re-draw on input change
  template: `
              <ion-button color="{{color}}" (click)="action.emit(null)" [disabled]="condition">
                {{title}}
              </ion-button>
            `
})
```

If you are just passing an `@Input()` to the template you can change the `changeStratergy` to `OnPush`.

If you also want to use an `@Input()` inside the component you can add `ngOnChanges` to trigger functions that need to be fired when the `@Input()` is changed.

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

`OnPush` can speed up your app quite a bit if you have lots of components on the page at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
<ion-button color="{{color}}" (click)="action.emit(null)" [disabled]="condition">                    
  {{title}}
</ion-button>
```

Comment: accuses the following error: 
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{condition}}]

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
[attr.disabled]="condition ? '' : null"
```

instead of directly using `disabled`. That should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

try with below code

```
<ion-button color="{{color}}" (click)="action.emit(null)" disabled [attr.disabled]="(condition)?condition:null">                    

 {{title}}</ion-button>
```

[attr.disabled] will remove the **disabled** attribute if **condition** value is found to be false